# When I quit remote SSH connection,tomcat will exit .So why?

Tags: tomcat

When I quit remote SSH connection,tomcat will exit.So why?
btw: No any errors in log files.
Help me please!Thanks

Comment: Could you possibly tell us what you have tried already if any ;-) this should help people from asking you to try the same steps again

Comment: nohup,screen, +&, all i have tried!

Answer (score 3):

From the sounds of it, it sounds as tho you are running tomcat under your login,

from SSH start tomcat (/etc/init.d/tomcat start) I think this should start it with the user that tomcat is specified to use

if not you can start it with the full install path and add an and (&!) sign at the end to run in the background

Comment: Agree with Trozz, even though his answer has something of a poem ;-).

Comment: `&` gets a background process but not detached from the shell, isn't `&!` better at that?

Comment: ;-) wasn't meant to be, was trying to remember tomcat as i haven't used it in a long time but sadly it sounds as though my answer wouldn't work for CatWin

Comment: I agree with lapo &! would be better than just & sorry for the incorrect symbol :-)

Comment: That's why we don't use /etc/init.d/script in general :> It's better to use service script restart because the application is started with proper user environment (If you use /etc/init.d/ the service will have your environment )

Answer (score 0):

if tomcat is downloaded from apache website then using (&) sign will not work you need to use [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) command

Comment: it's not ok.I have tried it.

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded a tomcat binary from the Apache website, it ships with a startup script in $CATALINA_HOME/bin, either startup.bat or startup.sh. There is also a shutdown script in the same directory. From the RUNNING.txt in $CATALINA_HOME

```
(3) Start Up Tomcat

(3.1) Tomcat can be started by executing the following commands:

  $CATALINA_HOME\bin\startup.bat          (Windows)

  $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh           (Unix)
```

$CATALINA_HOME will be where you unarchived the file you downloaded for tomcat.